# FBX export animation not smooth

Tags: animation, constraints

I started learning Blender a week ago and now I'm having problems with animation when exporting my .blend file to FBX (two arms holding a weapon). The animation isn't "perfect" so to speak.

The first gif shows the correct animation in my blender file;
the second gif shows the incorrect animation when importing the FBX.

[image: good]

[image: wrong]

The hand isn't holding the weapon's grip as it should; it moves around it.

The hand has bone constraints so that it moves where the grip's bone moves to.
The grip's bone is parented to another bone, which moves the entire weapon.
The animations look equally bad when imported in Blender or other software such as Unity.

What could be the problem? Should I upload my blender file so someone can take a look at it?

Comment: Seems like animation compression is on.  I know Unity has animation compress that it *can* do when it imports a .blend file (so you don't need to export the .fbx yourself).  Try turning off animation compression in Unity.

Comment: Problem persists if I turn animation compression off. It also looks wrong if I import the FBX in blender, so it's not a Unity problem.

Comment: Now it works. I added a keyframe for every frame (bake action can do this), turned off compression like you said and now looks ok.
Thanks!

Comment: You could also probably solve this by setting 'Simplify' to a smaller value or even 0.0 (in Animation part of FBX export settings) - FBX addon actually does a whole sampling/baking of animations to (try to) take into account complex things like constraints and drivers, but then by default applies some simplification to avoid exporting too much keyframes.

Comment: mont29, setting 'Simplify' to zero has finally made it work. This and disabling compression in Unity makes the animation look perfect.
Thank you all for helping!

Comment: @mont29 Good eye.  I haven't used the .fbx exporter in Blender, only let Unity import .blends (which uses the .fbx exporter, but brings out settings in a different layout in Unity).  Now I know for future reference, thanks!